# Jasmine - "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined thrown"

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I just started writing unit tests for an existing Angular app using Jasmine, and around 50% of the time, I get the following error:

> Chrome 72.0.3626 (Mac OS X 10.14.3) ERROR   {
>       "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined thrown",
>       "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined thrown"   } Chrome
>   72.0.3626 (Mac OS X 10.14.3): Executed 131 of 148 (1 FAILED) ERROR (51.175 secs / 50.533 secs)

[image]

The other 50% of the time, all tests pass without any issues.

The major problem I have with this error message is that Jasmine is not telling me where the issue is, while if I write in any tests of mine e.g `expect(true).toBe(false)`, then Jasmine tells me where and when `expect(true).toBe(false)` failed.

How could I find where this error is coming from? Did anybody experience any inconsistency in Jasmine?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: it says 1 FAILED, if you scroll up in the cmd window, it should tell you which test failed. Chances are good it failed because of that exception

Comment: There is nothing up there except for logs. Our test results go into a js-tests.xml file under /src, but the results in there is not consistent.

Comment: @UğurDinç
Looks like one of the value you are trying to use in the spec is not defined.
One more thing are you using any Observable's in your code and subscribing to that Observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved the issue after many hours of digging.

The error messages in the console started making more sense after the setting the random flag to false in `karma.conf.js` .

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    }
  })
}
```

In our case, one of our tests were failing due to not properly handling an async call in one of the components. Removing that test fixed the inconsistency issue.

Even though the message in the console was still not able to pinpoint the originator of the error, it was at least able to show the component / test suite that the error came from.

Comment: @DavidFindlay I can't remember exactly, but if I had to guess, I'd say it was an api call that wasn't properly spied / returned. To ensure that all goes smooth, make sure that you spy each and every one of your service calls in the `beforeEach` and write your tests after that.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me hours of debugging :). By turning on this flag i could at least detect which suite was throwing the error and digging around i found out where the issue was.